# Self employment, how to fill my annual income?

Tags: visas, uk, international-travel, standard-visitor-visas

I am helping my dad to apply for a UK visitor visa to visit me as I am settled here. I am sending an invitation letter and he will be staying at the house I am renting.

The question I have is that I don't really know how to properly fill the form. He is a dentist and self employed since 25 years ago. To give you generics the business ears 6000USD a month but the business spends around 3000USD month in rent, salary of his employees etc.  According to the accountant his main salary would surround the 3000USD monthly and I ask her to make a proper document saying that, plus the proof of ownership and the tax documents showing the business entries last 6 MONTHS.

But, as its him, an assistant and a secretary, he manages everything himself, buying supplies, paying rent, etc, using this specific bank account under his name (the business is also legally under his name).
So what should be his annual income, the 3000 monthly?? Or should I write the annual income of the whole business and where they ask how much he spends monthly include the business expenses per month?

I might be overthinking this, as I used to apply as an employee, that was straight forward but I can't seem to find how to do it for self employment in visitor visa cases.
Like he has applied multiple times for USA visas no problem so it should be fairly straight forward right.

Comment: For tax purposes, he should have some numbers for "income" (which usually do not include business expenses). You do no need to do a new accounting just for visa.

Answer (score 3):

Co-mingling of business and personal funds unfortunately does make this a bit complicated. To summarise: Your father's business operates from his personal account. Income for his business goes into it, expenses for his business goes out of it, and whatever is leftover is basically his salary, although presumably things like annual and irregular business expenses also go out of his account, making it hard to work out what his actual income is.

As a baseline, his income should be recorded as 3000 in your example, but you're going to need to submit additional evidence to show that he is legitimately self employed, and that this is an accurate reflection of his income. My impression is that UKVI are especially sceptical of self employment, because it is easy to synthesise a bank statement which claims to show self employment income by moving around savings.

Such evidence could include but is not limited to: anything he needs to submit to the government as part of his business operations, such as tax statements and business registration, accounts signed off by an accountant, evidence of his professional registration (ie proof he is legally practicing as a dentist).

It may be advisable to submit more than 6 months evidence, so as to give an accurate picture of his income (because eg, taxes may be paid in a lump sum at one point in the year).

And lastly, a complete but concise explanation of his business and what all the documents you've submitted mean should be included in a cover letter.

Any documents not in English (or Welsh) must be accompanied by a professional translation.